# Scala Transform recursive function with a map inside to tail recursion

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion, map-function

I have an object, let's call it RT, with two fields: a string and a List of itself.

```
def case class RT[String](topic: String, children: List[RT[String]])
```

And now I have the following function with recursion:

```
def func(tree: RT[String]): List[String] = {
  tree.children match  {
    case Nil=> List(tree.topic)
    case child =>
      val subTrees = child.map(rt => func(rt))
      subTrees.foldLeft(List(tree.topic))((acc,list) => acc ::: list ::: List(tree.topic))
  }
}
```

This gets me what I want. But, in very nested cases I get a StackOverflow, so I wish to transform the previous function into its tail-recursive form. However, I cannot see how. Is it possible?

Comment: While your question is not technically a duplicate, you wouldn't have needed to ask it if you had read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603912/why-is-this-scala-concatenation-function-not-tail-recursive).

Comment: @Malvolio Still doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me simplify your original code, a lot:

```
case class RT(topic: String, children: List[RT])

def func(tree: RT): List[String] =
  tree.topic :: tree.children.flatMap(rt => func(rt))
```

(To borrow from Inigo Montoya, I don't think `case class RT[String]` means what you think it means.  It is not a parameterized class built in some way on Scala strings.  It is a parameterized class built on an arbitrary type which you are calling "String" although it does not necessarily have any string-like qualities.  Later on, you instantiate the type-class with a real string.)

It's still not tail-recursive, so let's play the usual trick:

```
def func(tree: RT): List[String] = {
  @tailrec
  def funcAcc(trees: List[RT], acc: List[String]): List[String] = {
    if (trees.isEmpty)
      acc
    else
      funcAcc(trees.tail ::: trees.head.children, trees.head.topic :: acc)
  }
  funcAcc(List(tree), Nil).reverse
}
```

There, that works.

(We could have avoided the `reverse`, but that would have entailed appending to the growing list, and a whole bunch of appends are usually much slower than the same number of prepends and then a reverse.)

Comment: "It is a type-class ". it's not a type class. It's a class. A case class. But not a type class.

Comment: @pedrofurla - I couldn't find a formal definition of type-class in Scala.  All type-classes are parameterized classes, but are all parameterized classes type-classes?

Comment: @Malvolio Did you run my code? Have you realized that I do no get the same result by using your solution?

Comment: @Alessandroempire - are you asking for a refund?